# How to use partial templates with map in StringTemplate?

Tags: stringtemplate

I've got a map of city names => distance-from-origin.

I'd like to use a partial with this map, and create something like so:

```
<ul>
<li>city1: distance1</li>
<li>city2: distance2</li>
<li>city3: distance3</li>
</ul>
```

What is the canonical way to do this with StringTemplate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<ul>
$amap.keys:{k | <li>$k$: $amap.(k)$</li>}$
</ul>
```

Comment: Ahhh!!!! got it, I guess I can't use hyphens in StringTemplate variable names.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that in ST4 the default is to iterate over keys (rather than values as in ST3), so, the 'amap.keys' should be simply 'amap'.